# Cannot show Android AdMob

Tags: android, view, admob

I added admob sdk 6.4 on my app but it failed to show on the app

the logcat shows following error message

?:??: W/?(?): com.android.internal.widget.SizeAdaptiveLayout@425f9e70child view android.widget.FrameLayout@424d1538 measured out of bounds at 95px clamped to 96px

and my activity_mail.xml is as follows

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/sexy" >
</ImageView>

<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >
</TableLayout>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="3sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="116dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pattern #1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pattern #2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="OFF" />
</TableRow>

<com.google.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tableRow1"
    ns:adSize="BANNER"
    ns:adUnitId="a152106a3311446 "
    ads:testDevices="37329DE7326D00EC" >
</com.google.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you include the jar?

Comment: I included it in the buildpath(external jars)

Comment: is Your library folder called "lib" or "libs" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put  tag inside  because TableLayout is the parent of  and use android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" property in TableLayout.

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pattern #1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pattern #2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="OFF" />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<com.google.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tableLayout"
    ns:adSize="BANNER"
    ns:adUnitId="a152106a3311446 "
    ads:testDevices="37329DE7326D00EC" >
</com.google.ads.AdView>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don´t know if this causes Your problem, but in Your AdView, you have to declare

```
   android:layout_above="@id/tableRow1"
```

but You had

```
   android:layout_above="@+id/tableRow1" <--the + is wrong
```

The second is Your adUnitId has a blank at the end (and by the way, don´t show Your real id here in stackoverflow)